Application compilation error. Could not find com.jaeger.statusbarutil:library:1.5.1
This application has already been assembled by another developer.
I get the following error while building the application
Could not find com.jaeger.statusbarutil:library:1.5.1.
Required by:
   project :app
Search in build.gradle files

in build.gradle is connecting a dependency
implementation 'com.jaeger.statusbarutil:library:1.5.1'
The project uses the following repositories
repositories {
   google()
   mavenCentral()
   maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

I tried adding an authorization token to maven { url 'https://jitpack.io ' }, I also tried to specify the username and password from github, but in this case I got a 403 error when trying to download the dependency.
